# how to store jsx element to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to reuse my jsx element in multiple places.

```
const value= <div>some text<Link href="abc.com">text</Link></div>
```

and I want to call value in multiple places.

I tried adding ' ' for the div but not getting element properly. It is returing as string. Can someone explain me the correct syntax to render jsx element to JavaScript variable?

Comment: Try surrounding in brackets `()`

Comment: What error are you getting? Where you are using `value` ? There is too much missing information

Comment: Side note: That `href` is invalid, unless you really have a document  at `./abc.com`. You need a scheme in front of it.

Answer (score 9):

> I want to reuse my jsx element in multiple places.

<s>You can't. It can only be used in **one** place.</s> It would appear that you can, I stand corrected by [Mosè Raguzzini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234087/mos%c3%a8-raguzzini), this works just fine::

```
const value= <div>some text<Link href="http://example.com">text</Link></div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {value}
    {value}
    {value}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const value= <div>some text<a href="http://example.com">text</a></div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {value}
    {value}
    {value}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Another approach is to have a function that creates identical copies of it:

```
const getValue = () => <div>some text<Link href="abc.com">text</Link></div>;
```

Then when you want one, use `getValue()` to get it.

Or even give that a capital letter so it's a functional component:

```
const Value = () => <div>some text<Link href="abc.com">text</Link></div>;
```

Live Example (of both):

```js
const getValue = () => <div>some text<a href="http://example.com">text</a></div>;

const Value = () => <div>some text<a href="http://example.com">text</a></div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {getValue()}
    {getValue()}
    <Value />
    <Value />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

> how to store jsx element to javascript variable

You can't *reuse* a React element the way you've shown, but there's nothing wrong with:

```
const value= <div>some text<Link href="abc.com">text</Link></div>
```

(other than relying on ASI at the end, because there's no `;`). That works just fine. But it doesn't make it reusable.

Here's an example doing that:

```js
const value= <div>some text<a href="http://example.com">text</a></div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {value}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sure you can reuse the variable itself: https://jsfiddle.net/qvhu38fc/

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini - **Wow**. Thanks. That is very surprising. Are you sure it's properly supported?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure it is.

Comment: Yes, also if you export it, it will be cached too

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini - Thank you again. Wow, that's a massive difference from how the DOM works. (I know, I know, don't generalize DOM concepts to React...) I've fixed it, btw.

Comment: Np mate, curly braces are evaluating every time the variable passed in. That do the trick, I suppose.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini - I get it now. `createElement` just stores the information about how to create the element. It actually gets created when being used. TIL something fundamental about React, thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a stateless component to reuse said component:

```
  import React from "react"

  export const MyComponent = () => (
    <div>
      some text <Link href="abc.com">text</Link>
    </div>
  );
```